# How toIntent Array Object in Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How to intent data API like this in Android Studio with kotlin language

[image]

I Need help for it

Comment: show what you have tried. stack overflow is for helping in programming and bugfixing, not suggesting/determining whole solutions

Comment: do you want to indent json file in android studio, or want to update a json value at runtime? which json lib are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create data class in Kotlin from JSON and you don't know how to do it, there is nice plugin that can help you out.
Go to File -> Settings -> Plugins and search JSON To Kotlin Class

When you are adding new class select Kotlin data class File from JSON
[image]

Copy your JSON response in class, set class name and click finish.

Comment: I have to create response class, how to intent data from response class